# Displaying an Image in a Jupyter notebook behind a widget

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a custom widget for Jupyter Notebook.  The widget does not automatically load when a user opens their notebook, due mainly to the widget state not being found in the kernel.  The feature at hand is to display an image instead, until the notebook loads.

I have determined that a cell containing the following:

```
from IPython.display import Image
img = Image(filename="eggsnspam.png", width=500)
display(img)
```

will reload its image properly when the user loads the notebook.

The widget has code in it to generate a PNG "snapshot" image of the widget.  I want to show this image such that:

1. When the user loads the notebook and the widget state is not available, the user sees the serialized image.
2. When the user runs the cell that generates the widget, the user sees the widget and not the image.

I have tried researching several ways of dynamically showing or hiding the image, but nothing has worked.  I believe the most promising untried approach is to show the Image and the widget at the same location in the output cell, rendering the widget in front of the Image in the Z order.  However I don't know how to lay out the two to accomplish this.

It is necessary to manage this in the widget JS and/or Python code, and not from code cells in the notebook.  Additionally, the widget has no `background` attribute, and I have not yet learned how to create one.  (Discussions prior to my involvement in this project liked the idea of setting the background to the desired image.)

Comment: Note suggested by the related questions:  The prior discussions led to a capability to show the widget PNG image inline in the notebook.  The aim here is to show the image automatically when the widget state is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The jp_doodle canvas widget has a "snapshot" feature
which stores an image of the canvas.  I think you could
use it do do what you are describing.

Please see:

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/AaronWatters/jp_doodle/blob/master/notebooks/Feature%20demonstrations/Snapshot.ipynb

from the jp_doodle widget implementation

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle

which has many examples of displaying images in canvases.